# Comparing cyrillic data from SQL Server table and Excel file with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, arraylist

Using ASP.NET I need to compare data loaded from Excel file with data in SQL Server table. It's data written in cyrillic.

Basically, after script creates an array list filled with data from database table, it opens Excel file, and list data from one of the column. For every data stored in Excel cell, I have to find position in mentioned array list.

I have same data in both sources, but script returns that there are no same data at all. I guess that is something related with cyrillic letters.

Part of the code used for reading Excel cells and comparing with array list looks like this:

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";

        Page.Trace.Write(getExcelSheetName);

        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
        con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelRecords.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write(row[0]);
            Response.Write(" ");
            Response.Write(MyClass.areasList.IndexOf(row[0])); // always returns -1

            Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            Response.Write("<br />");
        }
```

Can you help me solving this please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try to print on the page strings from both sources? Do they look the same?

Comment: Yes, of course, they are same. Maybe I need something more in table definition or in asp.net script?